# How to do a while loop in liquid/jekyll?

Tags: while-loop, jekyll, liquid

I can't find any info on whether liquid/jekyll can handle `while` loops. So either no one has asked this question, or Google isn't being very helpful. Is this not something that can be done? I'd essentially like to be able to do something like this:

```
<!-- creates the 'counter' variable-->
{% assign counter = 0 %}
<!-- while 'counter' is less than 10, do some stuff -->
{% while counter < 10 %}
  <!-- the stuff to be done followed by an increase in the 'counter' variable -->
  {% assign counter = counter | plus: 1 %}
<!-- the completion of the loop -->
{% endwhile %}
```

Comment: If you're trying to simulate `while` which repeats execution forever until a condition is met, try using `for i in (1..999)` (or a number large enough to cover a maximum possible number of executions) then use `if ... break ... endif` to get out of the loop once a condition is met. Admittedly it won't execute forever, but it's the closest approximation to `while`. Note: this trick is only necessary if you're not already iterating over a given array.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No while loops in Liquid.

Can you use a for loop like this for your requirement

```
{% for counter in (0..9) %}
  <!-- the stuff to be done followed by an increase in the 'counter' variable -->
    {{ counter }}
{% endfor %}
```